# How to implement isSupported() functions for the android maps v2 native extension

Tags: air-native-extension, android-maps-v2

I'm wondering what would be the best way to implement `isSupported()` method in air native extension which utilizes android maps v2.

I know that `MapFragment.getMap()` returns null if Google Play Services is not installed, but this can be checked only after fragments `onCreateView()` has been called. I would need to check whether device supports the maps before I show map on stage.

Is that possible and if yes, what would be the best way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try using [GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil.html#isGooglePlayServicesAvailable%28android.content.Context%29).

Comment: Thanks, I found that my self at some point (this is an older question), but it is a good answer so I'll accept it. Cheers

Comment: @tica It's a good practice to self-answer your questions and accept them, so others having similar problems can benefit.